# Print all shortest paths from a src node to a dest node in an undirected graph

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, breadth-first-search

I am pasting my code for:
**Given an undirected and unweighted graph, prints all shortest paths from a `src` node to a `dest` node**. In the example I use, the src node is `a` and dest node is `f`

I am representing the undirected graph via a `HashMap`

I have 2 very specific questions about my code. I am trying to trace it on paper to find the answer but not able to find an example to fully answer my query.

```
import java.util.*;

class ShortestPathsAll {
    static Map<Character, List<Character>> graph =  new HashMap<>();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        graph.put('a',List.of('c','b'));
        graph.put('b',List.of('a','f'));

        //graph.put('c',List.of('a','d'));
        graph.put('c',List.of('a','d','f'));

        graph.put('d',List.of('c','e'));
        graph.put('e',List.of('d','f'));

        //graph.put('f',List.of('b','e'));
        graph.put('f',List.of('b','e','c'));

        var src = 'a';
        var dest = 'f';
        var currPath = new ArrayList<>(List.of(dest));
        var parents = allShortestPaths(graph);
        List<List<Character>> paths = new ArrayList<>();
        printPaths(parents, paths,currPath,src,dest);
        System.out.println(paths);

    }

    static Map<Character, List<Character>> allShortestPaths(Map<Character, List<Character>> graph) {
        Map<Character, Integer> distance = new HashMap<>();
        Map<Character, List<Character>> parents = new HashMap<>();
        Queue<Character> q = new LinkedList<>();
        Set<Character> visisted = new HashSet<>();

        var src = 'a'; var dest = 'f';

        for(var key:graph.keySet()) {
            distance.put(key,Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            parents.put(key, new ArrayList<>());
        }

        q.offer(src);
        distance.put(src,0);

        while(!q.isEmpty()) {
            var node = q.poll();
            if (visisted.contains(node)) {
                continue;
            }
            visisted.add(node);
            List<Character> children = graph.get(node);

            for(var child:children) {
                if(visisted.contains(child)) {
                    continue;
                }

                if(distance.get(child)>distance.get(node)+1) {
                    if(distance.get(child)!=Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
                        System.out.println("found it again");
                    }
                    distance.put(child, distance.get(node)+1);
                    parents.get(child).clear();
                    parents.get(child).add(node);
                } else {
                    parents.get(child).add(node);
                }
                q.offer(child);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(distance);
        System.out.println(parents);
        return parents;
    }

    static void printPaths(Map<Character, List<Character>> parents,
                           List<List<Character>> paths, List<Character> currPath, Character src, Character dest) {
        if(currPath.get(currPath.size()-1) == src) {
            paths.add(new ArrayList<>(currPath));
            return;
        }

        for(var parent:parents.get(dest)) {
            if (parent == null) {
                return;
            }

            currPath.add(parent);
            printPaths(parents, paths, currPath, src, parent);
            currPath.remove(currPath.size()-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Inside the `for-loop` in the function `allShortestPaths`, I have an `if-else` block as follows:

```
                if(distance.get(child)>distance.get(node)+1) {
                    if(distance.get(child)!=Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
                        System.out.println("found it");
                    }
                    distance.put(child, distance.get(node)+1);
                    parents.get(child).clear();
                    parents.get(child).add(node);
                } else {
                    parents.get(child).add(node);
                }
```

1. Given my understanding of BFS, I am unable to on paper come up with a graph which will make me see this print statement at all `System.out.println("found it again");` I think the reason is that in my current implementation, a node may enter the queue more than once but once a shortest path is seen, and the way I mark visited, the same node *can never* be visited from a longer path? Basically, in short, I am trying to trace and find a case where the print can show up.
2. This one is more serious and I am not 100% clear on this. The `if-else` block has an else part:

```
else {
    parents.get(child).add(node);
}
```

Blindly says that add the node to the list rather than

```
else if(distance.get(child) == distance.get(node)+1)
```

Without the `else-if`, is it possible that I may have a smaller distance stored and it might get over-written with a larger distance? Again, I think that since I do the visited check at the start of `for-loop` this might never happen. Is it true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am unable to on paper come up with a graph which will make me see this print statement at all `System.out.println("found it again");` ... the way I mark visited, the same node can never be visited from a longer path?

Your analysis is correct. It can never happen. Maybe you got that code from an implementation intended for a *weighted* graph? In that case it is possible to have a plain BFS (with a plain queue) revisit a node via a shorter path...

> The `if-else` block has an `else` part: .. Without the `else-if`, is it possible that I may have a smaller distance stored and it might get over-written with a larger distance? Again, I think that since I do the visited check at the start of for-loop this might never happen. Is it true?

First of all, no distance gets overwritten in that `else` block, so that is not something to worry about. Only `parents.get(child).add(node);` gets executed there.

Two things can be true in that `else` block:

- `distance.get(child)==distance.get(node)+1`. In that case it is right to perform `parents.get(child).add(node);`, since we have found an equally short path that is an alternative to the one already found before.
- `distance.get(child)==distance.get(node)` (one less). This happens when we have two nodes that are at the same distance, and both are on the current BFS "frontier", but the `child` one happens to be still in the queue, so it was no yet visited. In that case we have this equality, and it would be **wrong** to perform `parents.get(child).add(node);` because the current path to that child is not the shortest.

Here is a simple graph that reproduces the problem:

```
    a (start)
  ┌─┴─┐
  ▼   ▼
  b──►c──►f (target)
```

The queue will first have `{a}`, then `{b, c}`. When `b` is popped, and we check its neighbor `c`, we get in the problematic situation. If in your code we initialise like this:

```java
        graph.put('a',List.of('b','c'));
        graph.put('b',List.of('c'));
        graph.put('c',List.of('f'));
        graph.put('f',List.of());
```

The output ends with:

```
[[f, c, a], [f, c, b, a]]
```

...and obviously includes a path that is not the shortest!

If we correct the code and have:

```java
    } else if (distance.get(child)==distance.get(node)+1) {
```

...then the output will have:

```
[[f, c, a]]
```

So you need the `else if` version.

Comment: thanks again for the best explanation. I just owe it to you for all the elegant responses you share to so many of my questions. Would love to meet you one day. I live in the US. Maybe you can start a blog or a youtube channel. The elegance with which you articulate the thoughts is just superb! God bless!

Comment: That's nice to hear!